# How to select the words before and after a keyword

Tags: sql, r, sql-server

I have a table called BomNarration with a column called Narration that contains a line of texts, and there is one keyword called "Rev" that exists in every line. I want to select the words before and after the keyword. One problem is that in different lines, the words I want to select have different lengths and the keyword can be in anywhere. Two example of the line of texts in the column is "do this that for such such GX-77568 REV A." and "Follow BW-8452-355 REV D for this this that that".

I am writing the sql query on R studio to send to a sqlserver. Right now, I can only grab 11 character before the keyword and everything after the keyword.

```
SELECT LEFT(SUBSTRING(BomNarration.Narration, 
    (CHARINDEX('REV', BomNarration.Narration) - 12), 
    LEN(BomNarration.Narration)), 11) AS Drawing,
    LEFT(SUBSTRING(BomNarration.Narration, 
    (CHARINDEX('REV', BomNarration.Narration) + 3), 
    LEN(BomNarration.Narration)), 3) AS RevNum
FROM BomNarration
```

I expected only the 11 character before the keyword and 3 character after the keyword will show up. What I want is only the word before and after the keyword to show up ("GX-77568", "A." and "BW-8452-355" "D").  But what I get is only the 11 character before the keyword and everything after the keyword ("ch GX-77568" "A." and "BW-8452-355" "D for this this that that")

The result table on my screen

```
   Op Ln     Drawing                        RevNum
<       
1   1 10 ING 33B8222                             -
<       
2   1 13 RSC16A0019   D. AN NCR MUST BE RAISED AND
<       
3   1 20 NG C16A0019                             E
<       
4   5  2 SW-900-0009                             B
<       
5   6  6 SW-800-0004                             A
<       
6  14 24 SW-900-0078                             A
<       
7  15 12 SW-900-0078                             A
<       
8  16  4 SW-800-0006                             A
<       
9  22  6 SW-800-0006                             A
<       
10 25  4 SW-900-0008                             C
<       
11 27  3 SW-900-0055                             B
<       
12 28  4 SW-900-0055                             B
<       
13 29  3 SW-900-0055                             B
<       
14 30  3 SW-900-0055                             B
<       
15 36  1 SW-900-0255                             A
<       
16 36  4 SW-900-0266                             A
<       
17 36  8 SW-900-0057                  A. IF THIS *
<       
18 39  2 SW-900-0041                             A
<       
19 45  3 SW-900-0020                             A
<       
20 46  2 SW-900-0020                             A
```

Just to be clear, I would display the entire code

```
SELECT BomOperation.Op, 
CASE WHEN BomOperations.AutoNarrCode = 0
THEN BomOperationsStd.Ln
ELSE BomOperations.Ln
END,
CASE WHEN BomOperations.AutoNarrCode = 0
THEN LEFT(SUBSTRING(BomNarrationStd.Narration, (CHARINDEX('REV', BomNarrationStd.Narration) - 12), LEN(BomNarrationStd.Narration)), 11)
ELSE LEFT(SUBSTRING(BomNarration.Narration, (CHARINDEX('REV', BomNarration.Narration) - 12), LEN(BomNarration.Narration)), 11)
END
CASE WHEN BomOperations.AutoNarrCode = 0
THEN LEFT(SUBSTRING(BomNarration.NarrationStd, CHARINDEX('REV', BomNarrationStd.Narration) + 3, LEN(BomNarrationStd.Narration)), 3)
ELSE LEFT(SUBSTRING(BomNarration.Narration, CHARINDEX('REV', BomNarration.Narration) + 3, LEN(BomNarration.Narration)), 3)
END
FROM ......
```

Comment: Could you rewrite your sql query without quotes and commas and remove any table and columns that are not relevant for your question, clearly point out which column it is and what the keyword is and also add some sample data and expected output

Answer (score 0):

Three chars after 'REV' is

```
Left(SUBSTRING(BomNarration.Narration, CHARINDEX('REV', BomNarration.Narration) + 3, LEN(BomNarration.Narration)), 3)
```

DEMO

```
SELECT LEFT(SUBSTRING(BomNarration.Narration, 
    (CHARINDEX('REV', BomNarration.Narration) - 12), 
    LEN(BomNarration.Narration)), 11) AS Drawing,
    LEFT(SUBSTRING(BomNarration.Narration, 
    (CHARINDEX('REV', BomNarration.Narration) + 3), 
    LEN(BomNarration.Narration)), 3) AS RevNum
FROM (values
   ('do this that for such such GX-77568 REV A.')
   ,('Follow BW-8452-355 REV D for this this that that'))
BomNarration(Narration)
```

returns

```
Drawing RevNum
ch GX-77568  A.
BW-8452-355  D
```

Your code after the last edit works OK.

Comment: Sorry, but it doesn't work. The result is still the same. If there are more words after the work I want, it still shows

Comment: How it can show more words? This expression returns no more then 3 chars.

Comment: It show up like that when I use the code. I showed it in my last edit. Besides, I would like the code not to show 11 character before the Rev keyword, but to show the word before the keyword, that means only GX-77568, without that ch in the front

Comment: Also, for some reason when I tried your code in w3school's try it yourself page today , it refuses the statement and said your code has syntax error, but when I tried it at the same place yesterday, it worked.

Comment: W3school provides different sql products. Be sure to run it under Microsoft Sql Server. Unfortunately i can't see how one can force server selection. I  followed this path https://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysqlserver.asp?filename=trysql_func_sqlserver_ascii it works.

Comment: It works now. But still, my program (as shown above) is still behaving the same. If I pull out the text and put it in a separate sql query, it works like how I want it to. But if I put it together like the program above in my original question, it doesn't work.